# Insert vs Update

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where all the fields are declared as nvarchar. If I do an insert into the table all unicode characters come into the fields fine. But when I do an update I am losing some of the characters. Here is my udpate statement:

```
UPDATE TableII
     SET    LOCATION = CAST(( COALESCE([CITY], N'') + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
                              + COALESCE([INSTALLATION], N'') + NCHAR(13)
                              + NCHAR(10) + LEFT(LOCATION.LATLONG, 2) + N'°'
                              + SUBSTRING(LOCATION.LATLONG, 3, 2) + N''''
                              + SUBSTRING(LOCATION.LATLONG, 5, 2) + NCHAR(34)
                              + N' ' + SUBSTRING(LOCATION.LATLONG, 7, 1)
                              + N' ' + SUBSTRING(LOCATION.LATLONG, 8, 3)
                              + N'°' + SUBSTRING(LOCATION.LATLONG, 11, 2)
                              + N'''' + SUBSTRING(LOCATION.LATLONG, 13, 2)
                              + NCHAR(34) + N' ' + SUBSTRING(LOCATION.LATLONG,
                                                             15, 1) ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
     FROM   TABLEII
            INNER JOIN LOC ON TABLEII.REC = LOC.REC
            INNER JOIN LOCATION ON LOC.LOCRECNUM = LOCATION.LOCRECNUM
     WHERE  ( LOC.LOCSEQ = '1' )
```

As you can see I have tried a variety of things to force the unicode characters to not be lost, but it does not work.

Any ideas why the insert works fine but this update does not?

Comment: Is `LOCATION.LATLONG` nvarchar?

Comment: When you say you are "losing" characters what do you mean exactly? The string is truncated or they are being converted to `?` or ASCII equivalents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the City column NVARCHAR? If not, the COALESCE will take that column as it's data type and use it, regardless of what you do with the rest of the code.

Comment: No! I think this is the problem, thank you. I will accept the answer when I can.

Comment: `nvarchar` has higher precedence than `varchar`. The datatype of `COALESCE('', N'')` is `nvarchar`